# Syntax error near unexpected token 'newline' while reading data from file

Tags: c++, file, syntax, newline

I have a problem with my programme. I try to read data from the file like this:

```
./programme <input.txt>
```

but there is an error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'
```

in my programme I use getline for reading data:

```
while(getline(cin,string))
{
...
}
```

It works properly when I input data from keybord.

This is what contains file input.txt:

```
0.2 0.1 
1.2 0.2
1.2 1.1
1 2 0
0 1 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to actually *write* to the standard input.

Try one of these:

```
./programme < input.txt
```

On Unix:

```
cat input.txt | ./programme
```

On Windows:

```
type input.txt | programme
```

Comment: Better yet, the OP can use pass an istream to getline that represents cin when a file is not given and an appropriate ifstream when a file is given.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you actually literally typed:

```
./programme <input.txt>
```

That's a bash syntax error, because <kbd>></kbd> must be followed by the name of a file to which output will be directed. But there is no file, so bash complains that it unexpectedly found the end of the line.

Similarly, <kbd><</kbd> is followed by the name of a file from which input is taken.

So you presumably meant to write:

```
./programme < input.txt
```

Or you could have written

```
./programme < input.txt > output.txt
```

which would take input from `input.txt` and send output to `output.txt`.

(Whitespace before and after <kbd><</kbd> and <kbd>></kbd> is optional.)